# Find the same divs in DOM tree

Tags: jquery

I have a DOM tree:

```
<div id="all">
  <div id="second">
    <div id="target"></div> *
    <div id="somediv"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <div id="target"></div>
    <div id="somediv"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <div id="target"></div>
    <div id="somediv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How I can get all divs with id="target"?

`$('#second').siblings().andSelf().children(':first')`  - shows only the first target (*), ignoring the rest.

Comment: HTML is invalid id should be unique, `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have multiple divs with the same ID in an HTML document. Instead, use class="target". Then you can get all divs with the class target in all with

```
$("#all .target")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$('div[id=second]').siblings().andSelf().children(':first')
```

When presented with an id selector, jQuery will only return the first element with that id.
This is because having elements with the same id is *invalid HTML*. HTML parsers are generally flexible and will probably display fine in most browsers, however this is not guaranteed to be the case. Consider changing your markup to use `data-` attributes or CSS classes or similar rather than IDs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer; I will be careful in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You can not repeat ID in HTML.. replace `id="target"` with `class="target"` and then -

```
$('#all').find('.target');
```